FOSJsRouting Not Generating Routes with JMS I18n Routing
I am working on a Symfony 4.4 project with PHP 7.2, and I'm using the following bundles:

jms/i18n-routing-bundle

friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle:2.5.4


Problem
When I try to generate routes using the fos.Router.generate() function, the routes aren't generated as expected. They are being prefixed with locale-specific prefixes such as tr__RG__ or en__RG__.
For example, here's an entry from fos.Router.setData():
fos.Router.setData({
    "base_url": "/my-route",
    "routes": {
        "tr__RG__phone_services_ivr_request_listener": { ... }
    }
});

Command I Ran
To generate the FOS routing JavaScript file, I used the following command:
php bin/console fos:js-routing:dump --target=public/static/js/fos_routing.js
Configuration
Here’s my jms_i18n_routing.yaml configuration:
jms_i18n_routing:
  default_locale: '%env(LOCALE)%'
  locales: ['%env(LOCALE_TR)%', '%env(LOCALE_EN)%']
  strategy: custom
  redirect_to_host: false

Error Output
In the console, I am getting an error like this:
router.min.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: The route "search" does not exist.
Screenshots
Here are some screenshots for more context:

FOS Routing Routes:




  context_:
    base_url: ""
    host: ""
    locale: ""
    port: ""
    prefix: ""
    scheme: ""
    [[Prototype]]: Object

  routes_:
    [[Prototype]]: Object
    [[Prototype]]: Object


Console Exception:



the error below is an example for a search route I get the same error on all other routes it tries to generate


router.min.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: The route "search" does not exist.



Expected Outcome
I want the routes to be generated without any locale-specific prefixes (e.g., tr__RG__ or en__RG__), and they should be accessible through the fos.Router.generate() function without issues.
Question
Can anyone help me understand why the routes are being generated with these prefixes and how to remove or fix them to work properly with fos.Router.generate()?

The jms/i18n-routing-bundle did not have any changes released since 2021, so you may as well consider it unmaintained or abandoned.
Maybe the functionality that you need is supported by Symfony out of the box?
Localized Routes (i18n)

unfortunately I have dependecy to that package
